# Microsoft Teams -How to pass search text to the personal tab using Deeplink , so that the search field in the tab is auto-populated with the text

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am adding an app Similar to Wikipedia Search to MS Teams using Messaging Extensions. I also have created a Personal tab for a complete search experience which is basically my full search application embedded in an iFrame.

When I enter a search text to search within my app in Teams,I'm creating a Deeplink to take the user to the Personal Tab.
My DeeplinkURL is as follows -  https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity//?label=vanillaSearch
This works fine and directs the user to the Personal Tab, but  I would like my search text to be auto-populated within the the Search field inside the Tab , so that the user doesn't have to type the same search string again.
I've read the documentation for Deeplinks and tried using the subEntityID, but can't seem to get it to work. If anyone of you have a similar example, it would be very helpful.

**Update : Sep 13, 2020** :  I updated the Content URL in my Personal Tab to have a placeholder for subEntityID as follows : [image]

I've tried the following for DeepLink URL but nothing seems to work.

```
var encoded_query = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("{\"name\":\"" + query_name + "\",\"text\":\"" + text + "\"}");
var encodedContext = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("{\"subEntityId\":\"" +encoded_query+ "\" }");
var vanillaDeepLinkURL = "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/../sbaVanillaSearch?label=VanillaSearch&context=" + encodedContext;
var vanillaDeepLinkURL = "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/../sbaVanillaSearch?label=placeholder&subEntityID=" + encoded_query;
```

I'm not sure if I must pass the label parameter in the deeplink URL and I've tried passing the context parameter as per the documentation, but my search text is not populated in the text box when the tab opens.
I've referred to the following two links -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links
[image]

Comment: Subentityid is the right way to do this. Please post your full deeplink, including the subentityid, so we can try help

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Sorry I didn't notice your comment earlier, sorry for a late response.  I'm using a personal tab and the tab configuration only asks for Name , EntityID, Content URL and Website URL but there is no placeholder for SubEntityID. I don't see a place here to mention the SubEntityID. The DeepLink URL I'm using is - https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/c2be3234-3533-7658-z0ab-89d1c21a965b/sbaVanillaSearch?label=VanillaSearch

Comment: have a look at the deep links doc again (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links) - are you constructing your link properly in that format?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow After reviewing the docs again, I updated the personal tab configuration to have a placeholder for SubEntityID and I'm passing my query Text as a part of the SubEntityID in the deeplink URL , but its not working.  I updated my post with the details. Could you please provide me an example of how to pass custom parameters such as queryName and queryText to the tab using deeplinks.

Comment: thanks for the update, it helps to understand the context, and it's looking like this is a more complex scenario than it first appeared. A question - how do you anticipate the user being able to set that "query" value, when they install the app? When it comes to "configurable" tabs (i.e. tabs for a group chat or channel), there's a chance to provide a UI for the user to configure something. With a "static" (i.e. "personal") tab, there's no such opportunity...

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow So I have a search App that I've added to MS Teams using Messaging Extensions.( Its very similar to Wikipedia Search).  The idea is user enters a search keyword from the top search bar and searches within the app, but he/she can use a full fledged search application by clicking the deeplinkurl to the personal tab. Full search application is loaded in an iframe within the personal tab.  so I'd like to pass the query value that the user initially entered ,when he clicks on the deeplink - to do a more advanced search in the tab.  I'll upload a screenshot , so it may help clarify.

Comment: ah ok, got it now! In that case, you can leave off the "?query={subEntityID}" in your tab definition - the url is only parsed once, it is NOT dynamic (it won't evaluate "subEntityID" every time, unfortunately).

With regards your tab, I wonder if it's the encoding of the "custom" query text that's giving an issue. What happens if you have, for example:

Comment: var encodedContext = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("{\"subEntityId\":\"Azure\" }");
var vanillaDeepLinkURL = "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/a3be5658-3479-9476-d0ca-78c1b21a758b/sbaVanillaSearch?label=VanillaSearch&context=" + encodedContext;

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Thank you for the inputs, I’ll try it out. 
My deeplibk url will be “teams.microsoft.com/I/entity...&context=“ +encodedContext , is that correct??  Ideally when I enter a query text in my search application, I need pass the Json object &query={“name”:”Custom_query”,”text”:”Azure”}  this must be appended to the ContentURL for the application to run a search against the given “text”. So I’m not sure if just passing the query text will work, but I’ll give it a shot. 
Is the idea that whatever I pass as the subEntityId gets appended to the ContentURL given in the tab definition?

Comment: it's fine if your final iframe needs that, as you can build it up inside your page. For instance, if your main page is a razor page embedding the iframe, you can construct the final url to take the "subEntityId" of "Azure", and build the final {“name”:”Custom_query”,”text”:”Azure”} using that. That should be possible, from what I understand of your scenario

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I've tried by providing just the query text in the context and that doesn't seem to work. whatever my input is , the deeplinkURL just opens the Tab as per the tab definition and doesn't pass my query text to the Tab URL.

Comment: what about passing it in as the subentityid?

Comment: I tried both approaches , but no luck so far.  ```var encodedContext = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("{\"subEntityId\":\"Azure\"}");

            var vanillaDeepLinkURL = "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/../sbaVanillaSearch?&context="+encodedContext;  var vanillaDeepLinkURL = "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/../sbaVanillaSearch?&subEntityId=Azure; ```

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Another question on this topic -  when I click on the deeplinkURL , it opens up the personal Tab, but the focus is still on my search results list. Is there a way In can set focus to the tab on click of the deeplinkURL ?

Comment: So your link definitely doesn't look right - check the docs carefully - the subentitiy needs to be json, and url encoded. Something like this: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/[appid]/sbaVanillaSearch?context=%7B%22subEntityId%22:%20%22Azure%22%7D . As a side tip, work on it "offline" (i.e. out of your code), like in Notepad and keep testing variations - it's faster.

Comment: I don't understand your 2nd question - can you elaborate?